# JAX-WS generated schema version

Tags: java, jax-ws

I'm using JAX-WS (Metro 2.0) to generate a Web Service in NetBeans. It generates WSDL and xsd schemas. Generated schemas look like this:

```
<xs:schema version="1.0" targetNamespace="http://s.portal.org">
...
</xs:schema>
```

Is there any way to set custom schema version via configs or bindings?

```
<xs:schema version="2.3.4" targetNamespace="http://s.portal.org">
...
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried the `@Version` Annotation? I know its coming from `javax.persistance`...

Comment: As far as I know `@Version` protects fields from concurrent modification. I don't understand how this annotation can affect resulting xsd schema.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that `version="1.0"` is hard-coded in xml generator and cannot be changed the way I wanted to. So I ended up with this algorithm:

1. Generate wsdl and xsd using wsgen tool.
2. Change whatever you need in wsdl/xsd (version attribute in my case).
3. Link wsdl and therefore xsd schemas to SEI class via parameter `wsdlLocation` of `@WebService` annotation.